Expected ACC_001 (missing alt attribute) not being generated
I am using version 5.1.0, and I am using the --usage tag.
I am intentionally taking out the alt attributes from  tags and expecting to get ACC_001 errors. But I am not having the errors returned. I can generate other errors - even on the same image tags (eg: removing the closing '/').
When I run the epub through these two online checkers no errors are reported:
https://www.epubvalidation.com/
https://draft2digital.com/book/epubcheck/upload
But when I run it through this checker it shows the missing 'alt' as errors
https://bacc.dzblesen.de/
If anyone has any suggestions as to why this might be happening or something I could try to make progress, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
